# How can I avoid passing variables through multiple functions?

Tags: user-interface, function, global-variables, package

While doing GUI programming (in Perl), I often have the case where I have a main package/function x that calls a package/function y, which in turn calls package/function z. But, when I have a variable in x (e.g. a reference to a widget) that I need to access in z, I have to then pass it through y because I don't want to use globals.

Is there a better way to do this? As my program gets bigger, I seem to have more and more variables being passed through packages/functions just so that I can access them in sub packages/functions.

Comment: I think you *do* want to avoid globals.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the sentence to now read "I don't want to use globals," which is what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to think this is a bug.  It's a feature!  It means that if you come back to the program in months or years, you know how and where your data is being used.

Keep in mind that it is *not* in general empty information to pass a variable `a` through `y` to get to `z`.  The reason is that `y` might instead generate its own version of `a`; from looking at `x` or `z` alone you wouldn't be able to tell with global variables.  If you pass it through `y`, at least you know that `y` starts out with something generated by `x`.

Keep in mind that you also might find that you need to refactor your code:

```
x produces a
x calls y with a
  y produces b
  y calls z with a and b
```

could be changed to

```
x produces a
x calls y
  y produces and returns b
x calls z with a and b
```

in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I see the point about it not being empty information.